# PHP select distinct value of different row in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have  a database with two columns:

```
1. city : amsterdam, rome, london, amsterdam, rome, new york, ...
2. type : red, green, blue, red, green, ...
```

I have to select from a database the distinct value of columns and put it together.

The result must be like this:

```
amsterdam red, amsterdam blue, amsterdam green, rome red, rome blue, rome green, london ...
```

I tried with "select distinct" and with "array_unique", probably in the wrong way, but I can not get the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that you have two _tables_ or two _columns_? Could you add an example of what your data is and expected output?

Comment: You're confusing the terms 'table', 'database', and (possibly) 'column'.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as:

```
select city.city, color.color
from (select distinct city
      from t
     ) city cross join
     (select distinct color
      from t
     ) color
```

You are looking for all combinations of values from the two columns.  The first subquery returns all values from the `city` column.  The second all values from `color`.  The `cross join` is the SQL mechanism for producing all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, type
FROM table
```